# What are Sideband Pulses

Tags: experimental-realization, nielsen-and-chuang

I see sideband pulses used all over the place when looking up implementation techniques especially in Trapped Ion QC. Is there a layman's explanation of what they actually are? I understand what they do in terms of Energy Transitions, and how that is then used for gates; but I am struggling with understanding how these pulses can be tweaked to do nearly everything (In the case of the Cirac-Zoller Gate for instance).

My reference text has been Nielsen and Chuang, where they introduce sideband pulses in chapter 7.6; just for some context on where I am. Thanks!